# Create a Joint between Base_Link and Table object

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello to all respected Gazebo Users,

I am having trouble since last month getting everything to work. I am trying to put the base link of the UR10 robot to a table which is a Gazebo element and make it static so it doesn't move.

I have found out that i need to change the ur10.urdf.xacro and the `ur10_joint_limited_robot.urdf.xacro`. I added these lines to the last file:

```
 <link name="world" />

  <joint name="world_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world" />
    <child link = "base_link" />
    <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 1.2" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
  </joint>
```

it works fine as you can see the height is 1.2 meters away from the floor but it doesn't matter since I just wanted to see it.

What do i have to change in order for the robot model to spawn fixed to the table, instead of the World!

Thanks in advanced,

Kind Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8453/create-a-joint-between-base_link-and-table-object/) by [edo_raci](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1121/edo_raci/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When you insert your table inside an own xacro-file you should create it as table.urdf.xacro.
Then you need another file (e.g. table.xacro). The table.urdf.xacro is the description itself.
And the table.xacro is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="table" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
    <xacro:include filename="$(find myworld_description)/urdf/table.urdf.xacro" />
    <xacro:table prefix=""/>
</robot>
```

Inside the robot-file you have to refer to the table.xacro:

```
<xacro:include filename="$(find myworld_description)/urdf/table.xacro" />

<joint name="Table_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world" />
    <child link = "Table_link" />
    <origin xyz="0.0 -.7 0.7085" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
</joint>
```

It should work like this. You now just have to mount the robot like @nkoenig said.

---

Originally posted by [J_Schaefer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2326/j_schaefer/) with karma: 36 on 2015-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You have to create a joint between the table and the robot, similar to this:

```
<joint name="table_joint" type="fixed">
  <parent link="YOUR_TABLES_LINK" />
  <child link = "base_link" />
  <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
</joint>
```

You'll have to mess around with the `<origin>` value to get the robot in the desired location and orientation.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-04-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [edo_raci](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1121/edo_raci/) on 2015-04-15**:
I'm getting this error: [ERROR] [1429104093.856942772]: Failed to build tree: parent link [link] of joint [table_joint] not found.  This is not valid according to the URDF spec. Every link you refer to from a joint needs to be explicitly defined in the robot description. To fix this problem you can either remove this joint [table_joint] from your urdf file, or add "" to your urdf file.

**Comment by [J_Schaefer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2326/j_schaefer/) on 2015-12-02**:
I get a quite similar error:
[ERROR] [1449062411.299238060]: Failed to build tree: child link [Table1] of joint [Table1_joint] not found

I tried to include a table into my world in Gazebo.
The UR5, I'm using, is mounted to a foot, which is written inside the ur5_robot.urdf.xacro and this works.
When the table is written inside there, too, it works quite fine, but not in an own xacro-file.